# Why am I getting if: Expression Syntax when I try to run this script?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, terminal

I am currently trying to run a Unix Executable File in terminal (my shell is TCSH) I downloaded online and I keep getting the following error:

`if: Expression Syntax`

Here is the script I am trying to run:

```
if [ -f .1 ] 
then
cc -o xrdcalc .source/xrdcalc-1.1.c -lm
chmod 700 xrdcalc
./xrdcalc
else
platform=`uname`
echo
echo
echo "You are using \"xrdcalc\" for the first time on $platform , read the \"Readme.txt\" file and then proceed"
echo
echo 
echo "Press enter...."
read char;
echo `date` > .1
mkdir .source
mv xrdcalc-1.1.c .source
cc -o xrdcalc .source/xrdcalc-1.1.c -lm
./xrdcalc
fi
```

I have little experience with running scripts and I am sure it is an easy fix.

Comment: can you try with round parenthesis '( )' in your `if` statement, for TCSH I think? And probably `endif` to close it?

Comment: see also , [tcsh script if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799021/tcsh-script-if-statement)  , in tcsh , you need to have parentheses in place of square brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other issues with this code that indicate it was coded for traditional `sh` or `bash`.

Just put `#!/bin/bash` as the first line (using the correct path to your system's copy of `bash`), and it should work without other modifications.

Of course,

```
 chmod 755 scriptName
```

is also required to "mark" the file as executable and if the file is saved to a directory not in the path, you need to either `cd` to the correct dir, or invoke as

```
/full/path/to/scriptName
```

---

If you're using a reduced version of Linux that doesn't have `bash` installed and you can't install it for some reason, then look for other 'Bourne Shell' derived shell processors, like `ash, dash, ksh, sh` .

IHTH